# Oracle Data Dictionary best practices and guidelines

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges, data-dictionary

It is best practice to have PL/SQL code in my application that queries Oracle Data Dictionary views (all_tab_columns, etc...)?
Should this views be only used for DBA's and developers as they daily basis work?

Example: I need to verify if a variable can fit in a table column size. This will be asked inside a process called by any application users.

Comment: Don't go there. I would suggest, depending on web-tech/framework you are using, just catch the standard oracle exception, when the value is "too long" and show the user processed error message (Custom or standard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example may not be the best one, since there are other ways to do that.  For example, define the PL/SQL variable as `table.column%type` and then catch any exceptions that arise (due to length issues, e.g.,) when trying to put user data into it.

In general, I find it very unusual for production code to have to query from the data dictionary.  But, I have done it on occasion and do not remember having any special problems arising from it, except to remember that the PL/SQL object owner must have direct privileges on the dictionary and cannot be getting access to them via a role, since roles are disabled in named PL/SQL blocks having definer's rights.

Comment: It's my opinion. And catching the exception is what I suggested to do. But, I have difficulties to explain to my team that is not a best practice to do a query from Data Dictionary in production.